# Fastest way to view all-time SO ranking?

Tags: discussion

I've briefly looked over the questions and as far as I can tell, this hasn't been asked before, but apologies if it has!

On a users SO profile, if they've done particularly well in regards to earning reputation over a period of a quarter, year, etc, then there is the ability to click on the link ("Top 7% this quarter", for example), to show the users or your own ranking for that period.

Then there is the all time ranking feature, and I was looking, just out of curiosity, to see where I myself ranked in the all time list. But, since I have a low rep score comparatively, this was taking ages and ages of trawling through the pages, even with 50 results per page.

Is there some way that I'm missing that allows a user to find their own all time ranking in a matter of seconds?

**EDIT**

To clarify, using the leagues to find it did not show me my own ranking, only the top x amount of users.
[image]

Comment: Did you try: http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow ? You should appear at the top...

Comment: Isn't your own row always copied at the top of the ranking, with what place it is? (also that "Top 7% this quarter" is a link - if you change "quarter" to "alltime" on that URL...)

Comment: @JonClements I couldn't see myself on there, see the image I edited in.

Comment: @Oded Yeah, this worked, changing the "quarter" bit of the link to "alltime", thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row that shows where you are in the rankings is always copied to the top of the table, above everything else, precisely for this reason. There's one caveat: you have to be logged in for that to work. Looking at your screenshot, it appears you weren't logged in (the log in/sign up links are present), so all you need to do is sign in and you'll be able to find yourself.

Comment: Ohhh, yeah, my bad, didn't realise it had logged me out... Oops!